# Extract row indices where dataframe columns match

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'1': [0,1,2,3,4,5],
                    '2': [6,7,8,9,10,11],
                    'a': [3,6,9,12,15,18]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'1': [0,1,2,33,40,5],
                    '2': [6,7,8,99,10,11],
                    'b': [30,60,90,120,150,180],
                    'c': [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6]})
```

I want to extract the row indices of `df1` where `1` and `2` occur in the corresponding columns of `df2`. In other words, I want to extract the row indices of `df1` that would otherwise follow when making an `inner` join between the two dataframes:

```
pd.merge(df1,
         df2,
         on=['1','2'], 
         how='inner')
```

The obvious answer is to perform the `inner` join and extract indices, but I was wondering if there is a way to find the indices without performing the inner join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if use `MultiIndex` in both `DataFrame`s by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
mux = df1.set_index(['1','2']).index.intersection(df2.set_index(['1','2']).index)
print (mux)
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 5], [6, 7, 8, 11]],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]],
           names=['1', '2'],
           sortorder=0)
```

And if necessary convert it to `DataFrame` by [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html):

```
df = mux.to_frame()
print (df)
      1   2
1 2        
0 6   0   6
1 7   1   7
2 8   2   8
5 11  5  11
```

---

```
df11 = df1.set_index(['1','2'])
df22 = df2.set_index(['1','2'])
mux = df11.index.intersection(df22.index)
print (mux)
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 5], [6, 7, 8, 11]],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]],
           names=['1', '2'],
           sortorder=0)

df = df11.loc[mux]
print (df)
       a
1 2     
0 6    3
1 7    6
2 8    9
5 11  18
```

Comment: Is it possible to subset `df1` using these indices?

Comment: @N08 - It is possible select by `loc` with `df11` with `MultiIndex`. But `merge` is more clean in my opinion.

Comment: I see. But in fact I don't want to append/merge anything to `df1` yet, I just want to find the "intersection".

Comment: The final dataframe `df` now has `['1','2']` as index. How do I go back to the "original" formulation, where `1` and `2` are also columns?

Comment: @N08 - I think need `df = mux.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)`